# how do i map multiple attributes in rails with searchkick gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

here is my code which is working fine but i want to add multiple attributes i.e last_name, city etc.

```
def autocomplete
  render json: Doctor.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map(&:first_name)
end
```

I hope following explain my problem and you may got my point, Can i use following code.

```
def autocomplete
  render json: Doctor.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map(&:first_name, :last_name, :city, :country)
end
```

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643262/searchkick-autocomplete-with-multiple-attributes/28643845#28643845

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Doctor.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map{|doctor| doctor.slice(:first_name, :last_name, :city, :country) }
```

Comment: This causes the autocomplete dropdown/suggestions to show "undefined".