# searchkick - Autocomplete with multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, searchkick

Autocomplete works ok when searching with a single attribute as given [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#autocomplete).

Autocomplete with multiple attributes such as (name,city,country) is possible through->(according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081358/how-do-i-map-multiple-attributes-in-rails-with-searchkick-gem/21085634#21085634))

```
def autocomplete
     Doctor.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map{|doctor| doctor.slice(:name, :city, :country) }
end
```

However this results in the autocomplete dropdown/suggestions to show "undefined".

For type ahead i am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/typeahead.min.js"></script>
```

In the code it is referenced by:

```
$( function () {
   $("#search").typeahead({
    name: "doctor",
    remote: "/doctors/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"
  });


});
```

Is some change required in the typeahead js file because of more than one set of data being returned?

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed I am currently following your blog post and have asked a doubt there itself...

Comment: Use TypeaheadJS+BloodhoundJS bundle (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js)

Comment: After adding Bloodhound i have run into a few problems with implementing autocomplete for a single attribute also.Have added details here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654125/searchkick-bloodhound-typeahead-for-autocomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a `hash`

Your `autocomplete` action in `doctors` controller need to look like this :

```
def autocomplete
  render json: Doctor.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map do |doctor| { name: doctor.name, city: doctor.city, country: doctor.country }
  end
end
```

Add `displayKey` in your typeahead option:

```
$( function () {
   $("#search").typeahead({
    name: "doctor",
    displayKey: 'name',
    remote: "/doctors/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"
  });
});
```

You can also read [this](https://sharvy.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/add-robust-search-functionality-in-your-rails-4-app-using-elasticsearch-and-typeahead-js/) article and see if it helps.

Comment: Search on multiple attributes is also working now.Have posted my answer below.Please see if any improvements are possible.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the above answer and [this](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/224)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654125/searchkick-bloodhound-typeahead-for-autocomplete/28657029?noredirect=1#comment45611402_28657029)
What worked is shown below:

```
def autocomplete
    names = Doctor.search(params[:query], fields: [{name: :text_start}], limit: 10).map {|Doctor| {store: doctor.name, value: doctor.id}}
    collegenames = Doctor.search(params[:query], fields: [{collegename: :text_start}], limit: 10).map {|Doctor| {store: doctor.collegename, value: doctor.id}}
    render json: (names + collegenames)

end
```

The variable store: now contains all the data.
Javascript:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
    console.log("dfdf")
    var numbers = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('value');
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url:"/doctors/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"
        }


        });

        // initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine

        var promise = numbers.initialize();

        promise
        .done(function() { console.log('success!'); })
        .fail(function() { console.log('err!'); });

        // instantiate the typeahead UI
        $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
          displayKey: 'store',
          source: numbers.ttAdapter()
        });
}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Autocomplete works great on both fields however now i get an empty array on writing a url like

```
http://localhost:3000/doctors/autocomplete?query="a"
```

Comment: [My comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102146/working-twitter-typeahead-example#comment48130283_28102342) may address your problem.