# Searchkick + Bloodhound + Typeahead for autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, typeahead.js, bloodhound, searchkick

I am trying to implement a **simple autocomplete feature** for a single attribute.

*Model:*

```
searchkick text_start: [:name],autocomplete: ['name']
```

After reindexing the behaviour on the **Rails console is ok**.

```
2.2.0-p0 :002 >Doctor.search("a", autocomplete: true).map(&:name) 
gives the output-
 => ["a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa"]
```

After this i added the Autocomplete action to the controller and a new route to the routes.rb file.

*Controller:*

```
def autocomplete
    console.log("In auto")
    render json: Doctor.search(params[:query], autocomplete: false, limit: 10).map(&:name)
  end
```

*Routes:*

```
resources :doctors do
    collection do
      get :autocomplete
    end
  end
```

At this point if i simply test the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/doctors/autocomplete?query="a"
```

**Then i get the expected result in the browser**:

```
["a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa"]
```

Now adding a search box.

*_header.html.erb:*

```
  <%= form_tag doctors_path, method: :get do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: 'form-control typeahead', autocomplete: "off" %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

*And finally the Javascript:*

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
    var numbers = new Bloodhound({
      remote: {url: "/doctors/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"},
      datumTokenizer: function(d) { 
              return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace


});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine

var promise = numbers.initialize();

promise
.done(function() { console.log('success!'); })
.fail(function() { console.log('err!'); });

// instantiate the typeahead UI
$( '.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: numbers.ttAdapter()
});
}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

And this is the script tag used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
```

There is no response shown by the search box on typing anything,also there is no error shown on the console of Google Chrome.

Comment: try my solution, you need to return a hash with key 'value'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return hash in response of your autocomplete action:

```
def autocomplete
  render json: Doctor.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map {|doctor| {name: doctor.name, value: doctor.id}}
end
```

Comment: Just copied in your Typeahead.css.scss file and it worked.Thanks